# ColdFusion: Invalid XML Control Char (hex)

Tags: xml, coldfusion, char, hex

I'm trying to create an xml object using `<cfxml>`. I formatted all the data with `XMLFormat()`.
In XML there are some invalid characters like '»'. I added this chars to the xml doctype as follow:

```
<!ENTITY raquo "»">
```

The HTML text is not very well formatted, but most of it works with my code. But in some texts there are some control chars. I'm getting the following error:

An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x13) was found in the element content of the document.

I tried to add the unicode to the doctype and I tried this [solution](http://thenitai.com/2010/11/11/coldfusion-and-invalid-xml-character/). Both didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Here's valid cfscript code which cleans up our XML, there are two methods, one which clears higher international characters, and one which clears only lower ASCII character which was breaking our XML, if you find more characters, just expand filter rules.

```
<cfscript>    
    function cleanHighAscii(text){
        var buffer = createObject("java", "java.lang.StringBuffer").init();
        var pattern = createObject("java", "java.util.regex.Pattern").compile(javaCast( "string", "[^\x00-\x7F]" ));
        var matcher = pattern.Matcher(javaCast( "string", text));

        while(matcher.find()){
            var value = matcher.group();
            var asciiValue = asc(value);

            if ((asciiValue == 8220) OR (asciiValue == 8221))
                value = """";
            else if ((asciiValue == 8216) || (asciiValue == 8217))
                value = "'";
            else if (asciiValue == 8230)
                value = "...";
            else
                value = "&###asciiValue#;";

            matcher.AppendReplacement(buffer, javaCast( "string", value ));
        }

        matcher.AppendTail(buffer);
        return buffer.ToString();
    }

    function removeSubAscii(text){

        return rereplaceNoCase(text, "\x1A","&###26#;", "all");
    }

    function XMLSafe(text){
        text = cleanHighAscii(text);
        text = removeSubAscii(text);
        return text;
    }
</cfscript>
```

Other posisbilty is to user CF10 funciton encodeForXML():

https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForXML

Or use ESAPI which comes with CF10 directly or add ESAPI jars to your older CF from OWASP site https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Overview :

```
var esapi = createObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI");
var esapiEncoder = esapi.encoder();
return esapiEncoder.encodeForXML(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&#187;` instead of `»`. For example, this CFML:

```
<cfxml variable="x"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc
[
    <!ENTITY raquo "&#187;">
]>
<doc>
    Hello, &raquo; !
</doc>
</cfxml>

<cfdump var="#x#">
```

Comment: you missunderstood my question. The `»` was only an example (that works). What I need, is the code for 0x13... e.g. something that would look like &#013 (if that exists)...

Answer (score -1):

Pass your XML string through this method, and this will solve your problem.

It allows only valid characters to be sent in the input, if you want to replace invalids with some other character, you can modify the below method to do that

```
public String stripNonValidXMLCharacters(String in) {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(); // Used to hold the output.
    char current; // Used to reference the current character.

    if (in == null || ("".equals(in))) return ""; // vacancy test.
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        current = in.charAt(i);
        if ((current == 0x9) ||
            (current == 0xA) ||
            (current == 0xD) ||
            ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
            ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
            ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF)))
            out.append(current);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: I agree, it's not CF but solution is working solution in JAVA :) XMLFormat does just bare minimal cleanup, so eventually you have to filter all the weird ASCII chars out, wither by looping , using find or regex.